# What is wrong with this declaration in C?

Tags: c, hashtable

I defined a structure.

```
typedef struct bucket {
    char *key;
    void *value;
    struct bucket *next;
} Bucket;
```

This function is defined in a file called "htable.h".

```
int put(Table *table, const char *key, void *value) {

    Bucket insertBucket;
    strcpy(insertBucket.key, key);

    return 0;
}
```

shouldn't this be valid?

Comment: It should. What leads you to believe it isn't?

Comment: Runtime error here `strcpy(insertBucket.key, key);`

Comment: char *key, member of Bucket, needs to be malloc'ed before strcpy.

Comment: You've forgotten to copy the value, or set the `next` field, both of which leave you with some issues to resolve.  What is the `put()` function really trying to do?  How big is the data that the value points at?  How do you know?

Comment: @self. Well, then it's not a problem with the declaration. It's a semantical error.

Comment: @self. Honestly, I didn't even imagine that OP forgets the memory allocation... Eww... (Why is that so hard?)

Comment: @H2CO3 class String...

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you did not allocate any memory to the character pointer `key` and you are trying to copy a string to it. It gives you undefined behavior.
`key` is just a uninitialized character pointer and it just points to an random address.To be able to make use of any pointer there are two conditions:

1. It should point to a valid memory area &
2. The memory should be reserved for your usage (it should be owned)

You are violating both.

Comment: -1, Sorry to nitpick but a character pointer is not big enough to hold one character. You could do evil casts and store up to four, but that is bad code.

Comment: @self.: Fair enough, modified.

Comment: It's an uninitialized pointer, so it doesn't point anywhere useful.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - are you saying then that just before the line `strcpy(insertBucket.key, key);`, it would not be good to do something like `insertBucket.key=malloc(strlen(key)+1);` ?  if not, why not?   (also assuming other code including `free()` would be done also in same block)

Comment: @ryyker: No, he didn't mean that, he just stated the basic rule of pointer usage.How and where(from stack or from heap) you allocate memory to the pointer depends on the usage.It is a good practice to avoid dynamic memory allocation if you can, and use it only if it is required.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I actually thought that I didn't need to allocate any memory since I thought my key pointer in insert bucket would point to the copy instead of actually allocating memory to store in an array.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate some space to store your string. Right now you just have a raw pointer. Something like this:

```
char dest[80]; // arbitrary amount of space for example
strcpy(dest, key);
```

Ideally, you'd want to do this inside your `struct`

```
typedef struct bucket {
  char key[80];
  // .. other members ..
} Bucket;
```

Comment: How is copying the data into a local variable going to help? Or you proposing that `char dest[80];` replace one of the elements of the structure?

Comment: Updated to be more specific.

Comment: Better...maybe a length-checked copy would be a good idea (but beware of the fact that `strncpy()` does not null terminate overlong strings).

Comment: Or better yet, `bucket->key = malloc(strlen(key) + 1); strcpy(bucket->key, key);`.